# How can we explicitly write the distribution of this function of a discrete random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

The context is the unusually complicated formula for determining the critical strike multiplier in Warhammer 40K: Inquisitor - Martyr: https://mome-borogove.github.io/40k/20200707/understanding-criticals.html

The relevant values are theoretically real numbers, but the game displays individual sources in terms of percentage with one decimal place, and the totals as the sum of the sources, rounded to the nearest integer. So we can safely assume the random variables are discrete.

To formulate this mathematically, let $s$ and $d$ be fixed nonnegative integers and $X$ uniformly distributed over $[100]$ (the notation $[n]$ denotes the set $\{i\in\mathbb Z : 1\leqslant i\leqslant n\}$). For convenience we will also write $[m:n]$ to denote $\{i\in\mathbb Z : m\leqslant i\leqslant n\}$ - note that $|[m:n]| = n-m+1$.  Write $X_s:=X+s$, then $X_s$ is uniformly distributed over $[s+1:s+100]$. Then define
\begin{align}
Y_s &= \frac75\cdot \mathsf1_{[45]}(X_s) + 2\cdot \mathsf1_{[46:85]}(X_s) + \frac52\cdot \mathsf1_{[86:115]}(X_s)\\
&+ 3\cdot \mathsf1_{[116:135]}(X_s)+ \frac72\cdot \mathsf1_{[136:150]}(X_s) + 4\cdot\mathsf 1_{[151,\infty)}(X_s).
\end{align}
The critical strike multiplier is then $Y+d=:Y_{s,d}$. I'd like to write the distribution for $Y_{s,d}$ explicitly, i.e. $\mathbb P(Y_{s,d} = k)$ for $k\in\left\{\frac75,2,\frac52,3,\frac72,4\right\}$. If $s\geqslant 150$ then $Y_{s,d}=4$ with probability one, so we need only consider $0\leqslant s<150$. I could write an R script (or even an Excel formula) to compute these probabilities for each value of $d$ to produce a lookup table from which we can find $\mathbb P(Y_{s,d}=k)$ for given $d$ and $k$, but this would be somewhat tedious.

I'm sure there's a more elegant way to write the distribution of $Y_{s,d}$ (as a function of $s$ and $d$, where of course $Y_{s,d} = Y_s + d$), but the number of cases involved, among other things, makes it difficult for me to see how. I'm sure I could figure it out with a good hint, so I'd prefer that over a detailed solution.

Comment: I think there is a typo. Is it "when $\color{blue}s\ge 150$ then $Y_{s,d}=4$ with probability one..."?

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You are over-complicating, there are two random variables involved in a chain: the first one, namely $X_1$, with Bernoulli distribution with say probability $p$ to get a crit, the second one, namely $X_2$, uniformly distributed in the set $\{1,\ldots ,100\}$, with the relations

$$\Pr [X_2=k|X_1=1]=\frac1{100},\quad\Pr [X_2=k|X_1=0]=0,\quad\text{ when }k\in\{1,\ldots,100\}$$

Therefore

$$
\Pr [X_2=k]=\Pr [X_2=k|X_1=1]\Pr [X_1=1]+\Pr [X_2=k|X_1=0]\Pr [X_1=0]\\[1em]
=\begin{cases}
\frac{p}{100},&\text{ when }k\in \{1,\ldots, 100\}\\
1-p,&\text{ when }k=0\\
0,&\text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}
$$

Above $k=0$ represent when you dont get a crit, you can change this part but the distribution will be the same as far as the function that map values to percentages is consistent with the game, by example we can set the map $f$ by

$$
\begin{align*}
&x\mapsto 100,\quad \text{ when }x=0\\
&x\mapsto 140,\quad\text{ for }x\in\{1,\ldots ,45\}\\
&x\mapsto 200,\quad \text{ for }x\in \{46,\ldots ,85\}\\
&\ldots\ldots \ldots \ldots  \\
&x\mapsto 400,\quad \text{ when }x\in \{151,\ldots \}
\end{align*}
$$

All other factors are not random, so to evaluate "what is the probability to get $350\%$ crit factor or more" we do

$$
\Pr [Y\geqslant 350]=\Pr [X_2 \in  \{x-\lfloor m_1 \rfloor:x\in f^{-1}([350-m_2,\infty))\}]
$$

where $m_2$ is the percentage modifier added from your player, $m_1$ is the modifier added to the base crit modifier, $f$ is the map described above, and $\lfloor \cdot  \rfloor$ is the floor function (you can change it by the nearest integer function if you consider its best suited).

Comment: Your use of $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ is a bit confusing because $f$ takes non-integer values. I suppose what you meant by the notation was "the nearest value in the image of $f$"? Defining $Y$ as a function of a random variable distributed uniformly on $\{1,\ldots,100\}$ conditioned on a Bernoulli random variable taking value $1$ doesn't really seem to simplify the problem, either.

Comment: @Math1000 ah!, you are right, it doesn't took integer values. Fixed. But I dont follow what you mean for the other complains, it seems certainly more clean to work with my approach. You can took the identity given as a definition for the distribution of $Y$ (for some given values of $m_1$ and $m_2$).